# Collision detection of voxels and rectangles which are not axis aligned

Tags: 3d, collision-detection, voxel

I've got a voxel structure, representing a point cloud and a bunch of polygons in 3D, representing building facades. The polygons can be simplified as rectangles. For each voxel-polygon pair I need to check if there's an intersection.

I've tried AABB collision detection using the 3d bounding boxes of each polygon in 3D, but obviously the result isn't satisfying as the two objects aren't axis aligned. I could try OBB next, but I think there might be a more simple way to do this, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered constructing a polygon mesh from your point cloud? you can then construct a [BSP Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning), and use [CSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) to calculate intersections.